# how do you know when you fully integrated something

Tags: integration, trigonometric-integrals

How do you know when you've fully integrated something?

For instance, the integral:

$$\int \tan^5(x)\sec^3(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$$

Firstly, how do I integrate this, and secondly, how do I know if the integral is fully done.

Comment: What is the difference between "integrated something" and "fully integrated something"?

Comment: Here, you've "fully integrated something" when you've "integrated something"... just like you've "fully died" when you've "died."  By the way, here the answer is $\frac{\sec ^7(x)}{7}-\frac{2 \sec ^5(x)}{5}+\frac{\sec ^3(x)}{3}$.

Answer (score 1):

I integrate it observing that$$\int\tan^5(x)\sec^3(x)\,\mathrm dx=\int\frac{\sin^5(x)}{\cos^8(x)}\,\mathrm dx=\int\frac{\sin(x)\bigl(1-\cos^2(x)\bigr)^2}{\cos^8(x)}\,\mathrm dx$$and using the substitution $\cos(x)=y$ and $\sin(x)\,\mathrm dx=\mathrm dy$. And I check my answer computing its derivative and seeing wither or not I grt $\tan^5(x)\sec^3(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

1) Try something like $u=\sec(x)$, recall $$du=\sec(x)\tan(x)dx$$
2) The integral "is fully done" when the symbol $\int $ no longer appears.

Comment: I would rewrite the integral as $$\int \sec^2(x)\tan^4(x)\sec(x)\tan(x)dx=\int \sec^2(x)\big(\sec^2(x)-1\big)^2\sec(x)\tan(x)dx$$ Then, this is equal to $$\int u^2(u^2-1)^2du$$